# Differences between filter_var and filter_input

Tags: php

Why this doesn't work:

```
if(!($data['email'] = filter_var(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)))
{
    $errors['email'] = 'Invalid Email.';
}
```

And this is working:

```
if(!($data['email'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)))
{
    $errors['email'] = 'Invalid Email.';
}
```

Difference here is `filter_var` and `filter_input` and when I hit submit whit `filter_var` doesn't submitting the form but with `filter_input` is submitted. Also here

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL))
```

if I wrote for example `some'@email.com` why doesn't remove `'`. Is it working this function? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The difference is `filter_input()` won't throw a notice error if the array indice doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at arguments [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) functions take, you will see why:

```
filter_var ($value_to_be_filtered, FILTER_TYPE, $options)
```

**VS**

```
filter_input($input_type , $variable_from_input, FILTER_TYPE, $options)
```

Where `$input_type` is one of `INPUT_GET`, `INPUT_POST`, `INPUT_COOKIE`, `INPUT_SERVER`, or `INPUT_ENV`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And what about `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` why doesn't sanitize the email?

Comment: @Stan You are welcome ! Do you mean in `filter_var` ? Then correct syntax should be `filter_var ($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)`

Comment: I mean in `filter_input`. `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` doesn't remove  illegal characters from email.

Comment: @Stan `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` allows `'` character, take a look here [http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: It's so tiny .. I've missed it. Sorry about that and thank's for the info again!