# Difference between filter_var and filter_input on input data validation

Tags: php, performance, validation, filter-var, filter-input

What's the difference between using one of these two functions when validating user input? Strictly regarding the function calls, there's no requirement to change the $_POST array for instance.

> $result = filter_var($_POST['user_input'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

vs

> $result = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_input', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

Or there's no difference between the two calls above, not even performance wise, but rather just a matter of preference?

PS: I know there's a similar question on SO - [Differences between filter_var and filter_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049178/differences-between-filter-var-and-filter-input) - but that just states how the 2 methods should be called, not what's the actual difference.

Comment: I don't think there is such a difference, `filter_input` is simply designed to take an input as parameter and `filter_var` will take a variable so it's more generic (i'll go check the doc on that and make a response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request body does not contain the parameter `user_input` at all, `$_POST['user_input']` will trigger a notice, `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_input', ..)` won't.

Comment: Yes, so `$_POST` should be checked a priori against `isset()`, and if missing assign for instance `$result = null;`, while `filter_input` would return directly `null` in this case.
And otherwise, if the parameter is set, there's no difference?

Comment: Yes, if the parameter exists, there's no difference. The difference is precisely that `filter_input` transparently handles the case of missing input.

Answer (score 4):

From what i read on php.net,

The `filter_var` will simply work for any variable in your code, whenever you use it, it will check the value at that moment.

The `filter_input` value will check the **original values** of your input, meaning that if you change `$_POST['something']`, the `filter_input(INPUT-POST, "something", FILTER)` will perform a check on the value it had before you altered it.
It also doesn't seem to trigger a *E_NOTICE* on execution when the value is not set.

Reference post on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-input.php#99124)

Comment: Instead of "filter_var(...) will perform a check on the value it had before you altered it", you mean `filter_input`, no? That's why I mentioned that the `$_POST` array doesn't need to be changed, so basically then the difference remains as mentioned beforehand by @deceze: the notice being triggered.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i'm editing now :D
Still, having access to the original input can be quite useful in case your code gets executed after a CMS or framework that could alter the $_POST/GET... variables.